# If int *a = *b, will a point to the object that b references?

Tags: c++, c

Or will the address a be equal to the integer that b references?

Or will something else happen?

Edit: Also, if double *a = 3.0, does a point to 3.0?

Comment: It would be the one in your title, but `b` could be `nullptr` or something.

Comment: `double *a = 3.0;` shouldn't compile.

Comment: The question makes no sense. What is `int *a = *b` supposed to mean? What is `b` and where did it come from?

Comment: I sort of got this example out of a programming book, and the function was passed the argument **b.

Comment: @badatmath: It is the type of `b` that matters. `**b` doesn't say anything about its type either. What is the full type of `b`?

Comment: Well this was in the context of deleting an element from a linked list, and it was passed "IntElement **head", and the actual statement was "IntElement *elem = *head."  I thought replacing "IntElement" with "int" would make the code simpler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the code is `int *a = *b;` then `*b` is a pointer to an integer (has to match the type of `a`). That means that `b` is a pointer to a pointer to an integer. `a` would then contain the address that `*b` is pointing to, not to the address that `b` is pointing to.

However, if the code is `int *a; *a = *b;` then that's different. In that case you are copying the object that `b` is pointing to into the address that `a` is pointing to. The object has to be an integer, so `a` will point to a copy of the integer (so you could change `*b` and `*a` will not change). By the way, If `a` in uninitialised, that would be undefined behaviour (very likely a crash).

Answer (score 1):

The first part of your question makes no sense, since you provided no information about `b`.

As for the second part (about `double *a = 3.0`)... Both C and C++ languages prohibit initialization of pointers with non-pointer values (with the exception of null-pointer constants). This immediately means that `double *a = 3.0` is not valid C or C++ code. It simply won't compile. The same would apply for `int *a = 5` code, for another example.

In both C and C++, in order to convert a non-pointer value to pointer type you need an explicit cast. The result of such cast is implementation defined.

Answer (score 0):

`*a = *b` that means copy the content of memory with address `b` to the memory with address `a`

if (*a==*b) that means: checks if the content of memory with address `a` is equal to content of memory with address `b`

Answer (score 0):

> If int *a = *b, will a point to the object that b references?

It depends on what `b` is.

> Edit: Also, if double *a = 3.0, does a point to 3.0?

No, it is an invalid statement. You shall initialize `a` with an address.

Answer (score 0):

It must give you warning... convert `int` to `int *` without a cast
It also depends what exactly is `p`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int val = 5;
    int *b = &val;
    int *a = *b;

    printf("&val = %p; b = %p, a = %p\n", &val, b, a);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
&val = 0xbfb652d4; b = 0xbfb652d4, a = 0x5
```

(address values may change)

`a` will, in fact, be a pointer with the value that `b` points to. Unless `b` is itself a pointer to a pointer, `a` will probably point to an invalid location.

Comment: The code is invalid in both C and C++. It is illegal to initialize pointer `int *a` with value of `*b`, which has `int` type.

Comment: It might be semantically invalid, but I compiled and ran it; not even a warning is generated.

Comment: That would mean that your compiler is deliberately set up for "very loose" language conformity. I know that some compilers would generate warning for such code, which is already on the "loose" side, albeit formally sufficient (the language requires a diagnostic message, any diagnostic message). But if your compiler didn't generate any message at all... that's just strange.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer is reference of any variable and stores the location of other variable in it...
your example should be like :

double a=3.0;
int b*=a;

so pointer (B) will be refering the variable (A) with the value of 3.0